# Tricky "Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'" Problem

Tags: typescript

I have come across a Typescript issue that has me stumped.

The error is on the line below at `themeToChange[tileId][key] = value;`

The error is the somewhat classic `Type 'any' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

The error is 100% associated with the `TileLayout` type, as it's introduction caused this error. I can't see where I am making an error. If I add the value `"None"` to the `TileLayout` type, it resolves.

```
const changeSetting = React.useCallback(
    (key: keyof TileSettings, value: ValueOfTileSettings, tileId: TileId) => {
      const userSettings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings)) as UserSettings;
      const themeToChange = getCurrentTheme(userSettings, colorMode);

      themeToChange[tileId][key] = value;

      setSettings(userSettings);
    },
    [colorMode, setSettings, settings]
  );
```

Here are the type definitions:

```
export type TileLayout = "STANDARD" | "COMPACT";

export type TileType =
  | "Reddit Feed"
  | "Hacker News Feed"
  | "Strava Graph"
  | "Search Bar"
  | "Bonsai"
  | "Small Weather Tile"
  | "Large Weather Tile"
  | "UV Graph"
  | "Day Planner"
  | "Theme Picker"
  | "Small Spotify Tile"
  | "Time"
  | "Twitter Feed Tile"
  | "Markdown File Tile"
  | "Todo List"
  | "Large Spotify Tile"
  | "Small Stock Tile"
  | "Large Stock Tile"
  | "Spotify Top Artist Tile"
  | "Blank Tile"
  | "Favorite Links Tile"
  | "RSS Feed Tile"
  | "None";

export type TileSettings = {
  textColor: string;
  backgroundColor: string;
  tileType: TileType;
  tileLayout?: TileLayout;
  themePickerBubbleColor?: string;
  sidebarBackgroundColor?: string;
  sidebarBorderColor?: string;
  subTextColor?: string;
  subReddit?: string;
  twitterFeedURL?: string;
  stravaToken?: string;
  dropShadow?: string;
  cityForWeather?: string;
  cityForUv?: string;
  todoList?: TodoObject[];
  tileBorder?: string;
  stockName?: string;
  bonsaiBaseColor?: string;
  bonsaiTrunkColor?: string;
  borderRadius?: string;
  borderColor?: string;
  gridGap?: string;
  tempDisplayInCelsius?: string;
  hackerNewsFeedType?: string;
  spotifyArtistSearchTimeLength?: string;
  bookings?: Booking[];
  markdownFileText?: string;
  favoriteLinks?: FavoriteLink[];
  rssFeeds?: RSSFeed[];
};

export type ThemeSettings = {
  themeName: string;
  downloadedFromMarketplace: boolean;
  globalSettings: TileSettings;
  tile1: TileSettings;
  tile2: TileSettings;
  tile3: TileSettings;
  tile4: TileSettings;
  tile5: TileSettings;
  tile6: TileSettings;
  tile7: TileSettings;
  tile8: TileSettings;
  tile9: TileSettings;
  tile10: TileSettings;
  tile11: TileSettings;
};
```

Any help would me much appreciated! :)

Comment: try if this works ```<K extends keyof TileSettings>(key: K, value: TileSettings[K], tileId: TileId)```. this should infer the type of ```value``` depending upon key.

Comment: @AmitKumar That fixed it, thank you!


As a follow up question, how would I make this generic type usable in other places as a standalone type? So that I can use it in situations like this:  


`const defaultSetting = getDefaultSettingForOption(option, colorMode);
      themeToChange[option.tileId][
        option.localStorageId as keyof TileSettings
      ] = defaultSetting as any;`

Comment: @AmitKumar If you add that as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: I don't understand your second question, try to create a stackblitz sample, maybe then i can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

extract the key in generic type and use that for type inference of `value`.
like this: `<K extends keyof TileSettings>(key: K, value: TileSettings[K], tileId: TileId)`